# Box bug design editor Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I believe my Android Studio is having an issue with the designer as the boxes are not aligning properly with the project like they used to.

This is what it looks like:

[image: https://gyazo.com/4338718c044512778a4d3c1797a2d11b]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have inlined your image into the question (you'll be able to do this yourself once you have enough points here). However, I still find the question somewhat unclear. Is this in Android Studio itself, or is it happening in an app you're writing using Android Studio? What is it supposed to look like? Maybe you could show us the .xml files for this layout? Please [edit] this information into your question. With more information, maybe we can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issue was that I had to update android studio and it fixed the bug.